# Need to take max by excluding characters

Tags: r

I have a data frame x with column name "Bucket".

```
Bucket
0
1
2
3
4
4+
```

when i take the max of this column im getting the value as 4+, so how can exclude 4+ and get the output as 4.

```
max(unique(x$Bucket)) is something i have tried but im getting the output as 4+
```

Comment: What you want the answer to be if it were `5+` instead of `4+`? Do you prefer 5 or 4 in that case?

Comment: i want to exclude all the character variables such as 5+ or 4+ and only take the max of numerical variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to convert the data to numeric which would make enteries like `4+` as `NA` and then take `max`

```
max(as.numeric(as.character(x$Bucket)), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 4
```

Or if you want to read 4+ as 4 , 5+ as 5 you could do

```
max(readr::parse_number(as.character(x$Bucket)))
```

Comment: Put both as.character and as.numeric ?

Comment: @ARAVIND.S.RManu yes, because if the `class(x$Bucket)` is `factor` then using only `as.numeric` can give incorrect result. Hence, we first convert the data to character and then numeric.

Comment: it worked bro thanks i used max(as.numeric(unique(x$Bucket)),na.rm = T) but got a  Warning message:
In ~Bucket < max(as.numeric(unique(x$Bucket)), na.rm = T) :
  NAs introduced by coercion

Comment: @ARAVIND.S.RManu yes, that is because you have some non-numeric arguments like 4+ in x$Bucket hence it returns the warning when you are trying to convert it into numeric which is safe to ignore here.

Comment: thanks for the support, i have clicked on the check mark.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to replace the all the `4+` by `4` and then find the max:

```
x$Bucket <- as.integer(gsub("4+","4",x%Bucket)) # Turn all the `4+` rows to `4`.
max(x$Bucket)
```

In case you want to exclude all the `4+` and take the max of the remaining rows:

```
max(as.numeric(as.character(x[x$Bucket != "4+", "Bucket"])))
```

In this last case you have to include `as.character` and then `as.integer` because `x$Bucket` is a factor and `as.integer` will convert each category to their levels. This may cause some errors, so it's best to read the column as a string and then turn those literal characters to integers.

This step was not necessary in the first case because `gsub` returns characters.

Answer (score 0):

We can do

```
max(as.numeric(sub("\\+", "", df$Bucket)))
```